# React Native - How to present an activity when getCurrentActivity() is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-android

I'm working on a project which integrates 3rd party SDK in it.
The SDK method needs my activity to be passed in.

I'm doing this...

`processRegistration(getCurrentActivity(), someEncryptedString);`

and I'm getting following error...

`W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5b558ea`

I'm using [react-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation) and above code is called on 3rd screen(component). 2nd screen is 'replace'd 3rd

Can someone help to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been observed that in DEBUG mode you may face this issue.
To fix this, run it in RELEASE mode like follows.

`react-native run-android --variant=release`